# ESP HomeKit - Can not add accessory on certain router

Tags: homekit

I've followed the tutorials to install the LED demo from [ESP Homekit Demo](https://github.com/maximkulkin/esp-homekit-demo). The problem is that on my own network I can not add it to my home. It simply says *Could not find accessory* I can see no logs from the esp about any connection. I tried an other router and it works just fine. The odd thing is that I have Homekit accessories working on my network but I had the same problem with homebridge on a raspberry.

My routers model: sagemcom f@st 5655v2 ac rf

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the router does not support bonjour/zeroconf which is used to discover the accessories. I would suspect the router to be the issue (as you already write 'I tried an other router and it works just fine.'

On the sagemcom router, are the accessories and the controller (iPhone?) in the same IP network? bonjour/zeroconf AFAIK is not routed.